# Find index of value which is stored into NSDictionary and NSDictionary stored into NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I have `NSMutableArray` which stores `NSDictionary`. Consider following array which contain `NSDictionary`.

```
<__NSArrayM 0x7f9614847e60>(
{
    "PARAMETER_KEY" = 1;
    "PARAMETER_VALUE" = ALL;
},
{
    "PARAMETER_KEY" = 2;
    "PARAMETER_VALUE" = ABC;
},
{
    "PARAMETER_KEY" = 3;
    "PARAMETER_VALUE" = DEF;
},
{
    "PARAMETER_KEY" = 4;
    "PARAMETER_VALUE" = GHI;
},
{
    "PARAMETER_KEY" = 5;
    "PARAMETER_VALUE" = JKL;
}
)
```

I can find index of specific `NSDictionary` using following code.

```
int tag = (int)[listArray indexOfObject:dictionary];
```

But If I have `PARAMETER_VALUE = GHI` and using this value I want to find that dictionary index into array. I don't want to use for loop. Can I get index without for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `category` on `NSArray` like this (this does a type safety check as well; only array of dictionaries are processed):

```
- (NSInteger)indexOfDictionaryWithKey:(NSString *)iKey andValue:(id)iValue {
    NSUInteger index = [self indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(NSDictionary *dict, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if (![dict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            *stop = YES;
            return false;
        }

        return [dict[iKey] isEqual:iValue];
    }];

    return index;
}
```

And then simply call `indexOfDictionaryWithKey:andValue:` directly on your array object to get the index.

Just in case if you want to get the dictionary object out of that array, add one more category in `NSArray`:

```
- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithKey:(NSString *)iKey andValue:(id)iValue {
    NSUInteger index = [self indexOfDictionaryWithKey:iKey andValue:iValue];

    return (index == NSNotFound) ? nil : self[index];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `indexOfObjectPassingTest` method of `NSArray`:

```
[listArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(NSDictionary*  _Nonnull dic, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        return [dic[@"PARAMETER_VALUE"] isEqualToString:@"GHI"];
}];
```

Also, please consider using `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest` if you can have multiple dictionaries with the same `PARAMETER_VALUE`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**NSPredicate**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/) for this purpose:

```
// Creating predicate
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.PARAMETER_VALUE MATCHES %@",@"GHI"];

// Filtering array
NSArray *filteredArr   = [arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

// If filtered array count is greater than zero (that means specified object is available in the array), checking the index of object
// There can be multiple objects available in the filtered array based on the value it holds (In this sample code, only checking the index of first object
if ([filteredArr count])
{
    NSLog(@"Index %d",[arr indexOfObject:filteredArr[0]]);
}
```

Comment: Well, this has no loop in his code, but iterates twice over the array.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad: Are you sure that is how nspredicate and indexOfObject works ? (Means managing loops inside ?)

Comment: It has to compare every instance with the predicate. So it has to iterate. `-indexOfObject:` has to do the same, maybe it can use a hash look-up, but I do not think so. (This would be a benefit only in rare cases.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, one has to enumerate in a way. Taking your requirement literally (no `for` loop), you can use fast enumeration. However, the task can be run concurrently, because you only need read access:

```
__block NSUInteger index;
[array enumerateObjectsWithOptions: NSEnumerationConcurrent
                     usingBlock:
^(NSDictionary *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
{
  if( [obj valueForKey:@"PARAMETER_VALUE" isEqualToString:@"GHI" )
  {
    index = idx;
    *stop=YES;
  }
}
```